# Is there a way you can fetch SharePoint's more than 5000 items using datatable?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, datatable

Is there a way you can fetch SharePoint's more than 5000 items using datatable Jquery recursively in REST API? I also wanted to show the next set of data (next 1000 items) after clicking a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the $top property and you can recursive call the same function.

```
function FuncName() 
{

var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl ; 
var RestUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HelpDeskTask')/items?$top=1000&$select=ID,HelpdeskTitle,Body,HRStatus,Ageing,SLA,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID,*&$expand=AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID&$filter=TaskType eq 'HR'";   

$.ajax({  
    url: RestUrl,  
    method: "GET", 
    async: false,   
    headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
     } ,
    success: function(data) {  
    if (data.d.results.length > 0) 
    {  
        //Recursive call to read more than 1000 data from list
        if (data.d.__next)
         {
             RestUrl = data.d.__next;
              FuncName();
           var result = data.d.results;  //you will get the data here
         }
        //to do code here
     }
    }
    error: function(data) {
    //handle error here
    }
  });
}
```

**Update**: [To fetch next batch of records into a table on click of button]

Please put the below the below HTML code into a CEWP:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
loadMyItems();
$("#btnPaginate").click(function(){
    loadMyItems();
});
});
var siteUrl='';
var itemID = '';
var itemCount = 5;   //no. of items to display on a page
function loadMyItems() 
{

siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl ; 
if(itemID == '')
{
    var RestUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HelpDeskTask')/items?$select=ID,HelpdeskTitle,Body,HRStatus,Ageing,SLA,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID,*&$expand=AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID&$filter=TaskType eq 'HR'&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$top="+itemCount;   
}
else
{
    var RestUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HelpDeskTask')/items?$select=ID,HelpdeskTitle,Body,HRStatus,Ageing,SLA,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID,*&$expand=AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/ID&$filter=TaskType eq 'HR'&%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE%26p_ID%3D"+itemID+"&%24top="+itemCount;   

}

$.ajax({  
    url: RestUrl,  
    method: "GET", 
    async: false,   
    headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
     } ,
    success: function(data) {  
    if (data.d.results.length > 0) 
        {
        if(data.d.results.length <= itemCount)     //remove the old data 
            {  
            $("#CustomerRecordsTable").remove();
            }
        $('#CustomerGrid').append(GenerateTableFromJson(data.d.results));
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {  
       $('#CustomerGrid').append("<span class='currency_span'>Error Retreiving HelpDesk Records. Error : " + JSON.stringify(data) + "</span>");  
     }  
  });
}

function GenerateTableFromJson(objArray) 
   {  
    var tableContent = '<table id="CustomerRecordsTable" class="display" style="width:100%"><thead><tr><th>ID</th>' + '<th>TicketID</th>' +'<th>Title</th>' + '<th style="display:none;">Status</th>' + '<th>Description</th> '+ '<th>AssignedTo</th>' +'<th>Ageing</th>'+'<th>SLA</th>' + '<th style="display:none;">Date</th>' + '<th>Link</th>' + '</tr></thead>';    
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) 
    {  
           itemID = objArray[i].Id;
           tableContent += '<tr>';  
           tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].Id + '</td>';
           tableContent += '<td id="Ticket_'+objArray[i].Id+'">' + objArray[i].RequestID+ '</td>';   
           tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].HelpdeskTitle+ '</td>'; 
           tableContent += '<td id="Status_'+objArray[i].Id+'" style="display:none;">' + objArray[i].HRStatus + '</td>';       
           tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].Body + '</td>';      
           tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].AssignedTo['Title'] + '</td>';  
           tableContent += '<td>' + '-' + '</td>';  
           tableContent += '<td>' + '-' + '</td>';
           tableContent += '<td id="Date_'+objArray[i].Id+'" style="display:none;">' + objArray[i].TaskCompletiondDate+ '</td>';   
           tableContent += '<td>' +'<a target="_blank" href="' + siteUrl + '/Lists/HelpDesk/Dispform.aspx?ID=' + objArray[i].RequestID+ '">View</a>'+'</td>';  
           tableContent += '</tr>';  

     } 
     return tableContent;      
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="CustomerGrid" style="width: 100%">      
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnPaginate">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sohail, Thanks for your reply. I already did but I also wanted to show a button where I can show the next set of 1000?

Comment: @James I have added the code above to fetch next batch of records in to a table on click of a button. 
Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Comment: @James Pleasure ;)